# How to create a customize error response dto from ModelState with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#

I have this class which implement fluent validation.

```
public class MarketingEventRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateMarketingEventRequest>
{
    public MarketingEventRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(marketingEventRequest => marketingEventRequest.Name).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(marketingEventRequest => marketingEventRequest.EventDate).NotNull().NotEmpty()
            .Must(BeAValidEventDate).WithMessage("Event date must be equal or greater than system date");
        RuleFor(marketingEventRequest => marketingEventRequest.StartTime).NotNull().NotEmpty().Length(4);
        RuleFor(marketingEventRequest => marketingEventRequest.EndTime).NotNull().NotEmpty().Length(4);
    }
    private bool BeAValidEventDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return date < DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddMarketingEvent([FromBody] CreateMarketingEventRequest request)
    {
    // code removed for brevity
    }
```

When I test it, it straight away return error like below

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-e4b8b00b0204bd915763cb7243fdcc60-1646ac57370e44bd-00",
  "errors": {
    "Name": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "State": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "Venue": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "Remark": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "EndTime": [
      "'' is not in the correct format.",
      "'End Time' must be 4 characters in length. You entered 6 characters."
    ],
    "StartTime": [
      "'' is not in the correct format.",
      "'Start Time' must be 4 characters in length. You entered 6 characters."
    ]
  }
}
```

But what I want in my error response dto is just below

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string? Errors { get; init; }
    public string? Message { get; init; }
    public int StatusCode { get; init; }
}
```

Sample data will be

```
{
  "errors":  {
    "Name": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "State": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "Venue": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "Remark": [
      "'' is not in the correct format."
    ],
    "EndTime": [
      "'' is not in the correct format.",
      "'End Time' must be 4 characters in length. You entered 6 characters."
    ],
    "StartTime": [
      "'' is not in the correct format.",
      "'Start Time' must be 4 characters in length. You entered 6 characters."
    ]
  },
  "message": "Bad request. One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

How do I map the ModelState to this custom error class?

I tried to put it in create a filter by implementing `IAsyncActionFilter`. It works in some ways but when if I do so, it applies to all controller which I do not want to.

The reason is because there are many controller action method only take one primitive datatype ie int id. If I use Fluent Validation, I need to create a class. I do not feel like to create a class just to store one column.

Comment: Why would you use a homebrew solution when a [standarized error response](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807) format for HTTP APIs has been defined by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)? ASP.NET Core supports this out of the box via [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation-failure-error-response).

Answer (score 0):

Do You want to get this kind of response model only with Fluent Validation? or the approach does not matter?

So here is my approach, however I didn't use 'Fluent Validation' but the result is what you want, in addition i use it more dynamic but I made it simple for you, in this approach you could inject `ICustomerError`  in your desired controller and call `CustomError.BadRequestError(ModelState);`

So create an `ICustomError` and implement that :

```
public interface ICustomError
{
    ErrorResponse BadRequestError(ModelStateDictionary modelState);
}


public class CustomError : ICustomError
    {
        private ErrorResponse _errorResponseModel;

        public ErrorResponse BadRequestError(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            _errorResponseModel = new ErrorResponse();
            var errorFlields = modelState.ToDictionary(
                 kvp => kvp.Key,
                 kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                );

            _errorResponseModel.Errors = errorFlields;
            _errorResponseModel.Message = "Bad request. One or more validation errors occurred.";
            _errorResponseModel.StatusCode = 400;

            return _errorResponseModel;
        }
    }
```

and here is `ErrorResponse`

```
public class ErrorResponse
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> Errors { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally use Model Validation Attributes for `CreateMarketingEventRequest`.
I hope it was useful.

Comment: for consistency, if can, i would like to have to this custom model for all errors.